# Definition of tensor product using pushout.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M, N$ be right and left $A$-modules respectively. 
Then we have actions
$$
\varphi_M: M \times A \to M, \\
\varphi_N: A \times N \to N.
$$

There is a definition of $M \otimes_A N$ as follows. We have $\varphi_M \times \varphi_N: M \times A \times A \times N \to M \times N$ and $1 \times {\bf m} \times 1: M \times A \times A \times N \to M \times A \times N$. Here ${\bf m}: A \times A \to A$ is the multiplication map. $M \otimes_A N$ is defined to be the pushout of $\varphi_M \times \varphi_N$ and $1 \times {\bf m} \times 1$. Is this definition of $M \otimes_A N$ equivalent to the usual definition of $M \otimes_A N$? Thank you very much.

Comment: One direction should be clear: $M \otimes_A N$ satisfies the above definition along with the obvious maps $\otimes : M \times N \to M \otimes_A N$ and $\varphi_M \times \otimes : M \times A \times N \to M \otimes_A N$ given by $\otimes (m,n) = m \otimes n$ and $(\varphi_M \times \otimes) (m,a,n) = (ma) \otimes n$. Now can you show the reverse direction i.e. if X is a pushout as above, then it is the tensor product $M \otimes_A N$?

Comment: What category are you taking the pushout in?